# Carbon diff in days unexpected result

Tags: php, php-carbon

So I have 2 carbon date

1. date: 2020-10-28 12:17:30.595661 Asia/Jakarta (+07:00)
2. date: 2020-10-01 12:24:02.0 Asia/Jakarta (+07:00)

I use `$now->diffInDays($date);`

I expect 27 to be the result, but the result is 26. I thinks its because the hour.

How can I get 27 for this case?

Thanks

Comment: `-> floatDiffInDays()` shows `26.995469857187` by the way so it must've rounded it off

Comment: Oh great, but how to round or ceil it? I'm afraid that when the expected result is 27 but it turn to 28 because i round it before the day changes.

Comment: if you want to apply rounding 26.99 as 27 you need to make the decision or follow what your requirements are. you can tweak `round()` function depending on precision